# Getting child data of last child without having NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to have the last child of my database. Then I want to get the `UserId` data of that child in a string variable. But it is showing `NullPointerException`.

In my database there is the root "key". 
It has UserId children like `8ZkecDpTTMT9TSE1y0DdldrB3Sf1, ZOmMn1cKLbfB5r4jrd2u5I7BvaT2` ; each having the child named `UserId` that has its own values (i.e. `ZOmMn1cKLbfB5r4jrd2u5I7BvaT2` has child `UserId` that contains `ZOmMn1cKLbfB5r4jrd2u5I7BvaT2` itself).
I want to get the last child (which is `ZOmMn1cKLbfB5r4jrd2u5I7BvaT2`) and get its value from `UserId`.
This is the database:

[image]

(The root LUQ78iCK.... is the KEY which I have used in the database. 'Key' is a string which I have successfully got with some program)

This is what I am trying:

```
String userdata;

final DatabaseReference key= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tag");

Query keyquery= key.child(Key).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);


keyquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        userdata= dataSnapshot.child("UserId").getValue().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I am having this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.zub.backup, PID: 18285
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.zub.backup.HomeFragment$2$3$1.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:367)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)
```

P.S.- The **error** is in the line

> userdata= dataSnapshot.child("UserId").getValue().toString();

Comment: Please add your database structure to see it more clearly.

Comment: Added. Please check it.

Comment: Cand you please add a more detailed one, including the upper nodes? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the whole tree. The root "Tag" is not so relevant with my problem, so I excluded it from the problem in stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the value of `key` in this line `key.child(Key)`?